# using subquery with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I am trying to execute the select statement below but I get this error:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

I tried to change the code and google how I can make it return correct data but I could not find anything useful.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT id, mult(x, y) FROM multTable WHERE (SELECT mult(x, y) FROM multTable) > 20;
```

Note, in multTable there are columns for x and y, which both have a couple of values.

How do I go about making sure I do not receive that error?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `(SELECT mult(x, y) FROM multTable) ` gives you several rows, so it cant' be used to define if statement is true or not

Comment: Oh ya I get that now, thanx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you want:

```
SELECT id, mult(x, y) FROM multTable WHERE mult(x, y) > 20;
```

Comment: Thanx for your help, it actually worked and is less complicated than what I was doing.